# Axis1 on Wildlfy

Tags: maven, jboss, wildfly, apache-axis, wildfly-10

Trying to deploy a war on Wildfly 10.0.0. Final standalone got the following error :

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc.setXmlType(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;)V"
the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, mypackage/MyClass,
and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/apache/axis/description/TypeDesc,
have different Class objects for the type javax/xml/namespace/QName used in the signature
```

wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules\org\apache\axis\jaxrpc\main\axis-jaxrpc-1.4.jar\javax\xml\namespace\QName.class major version: 47
jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\rt.jar\javax\xml\namespace\QName.class major version: 52

I have read the [Class Loading in WildFly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly) but have no idea what the proper "specific order" is:

> A common source of errors in Java applications is including API
>   classes in a deployment that are also provided by the container. This
>   can result in multiple versions of the class being created and the
>   deployment failing to deploy properly. To prevent this in WildFly,
>   module dependencies are added in a specific order that should prevent
>   this situation from occurring.

jboss-deployment-structure.xml contains:

```
<module name="org.apache.axis.axis" />
```

pom.xml contains:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>axis</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules\org\apache\axis\axis\main\module.xml:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.apache.axis.axis">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="axis-1.4.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="org.apache.axis.jaxrpc"/>
    <module name="org.apache.axis.saaj"/>
    <module name="org.apache.axis.wsdl4j"/>
    <module name="org.apache.commons.discovery"/>
    <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
    <module name="javax.activation.api"/>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.mail.api"/>
    <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules\org\apache\axis\jaxrpc\main\module.xml:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.apache.axis.jaxrpc">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="axis-jaxrpc-1.4.jar"/>
  </resources>
</module>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Local Resource instead of User Dependencies solved the problem.
From jboss-deployment-structure.xml removed:

```
<module name="org.apache.axis.axis" />
```

pom.xml (no provided scope anymore):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis-jaxrpc</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis-saaj</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>axis</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis-wsdl4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>axis</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```